# React Login application for OAuth2.0 login with Spring Security Authorization server

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-security, spring-authorization-server

After releasing the 1.0.0 version of the spring security authorization server we want to migrate from our current custom auth server to the OpenId.

But we want still to have our login page with our design developed using React JS.
I do trials to do it using the spring authorization server running on port 9000 and simply react app running on the 3000 port.

My React application when the user opens it in the browser starts the OpenId Authorization Code flow using the request `http://localhost:9000/oauth2/authorize?redirect_url=http://localhost:3000/profile&scope=openid%20profile&client_id=articles-client&response_type=code`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import './App.css';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:9000",
});

function Init() {

  useEffect(() => {
    const initState = async () => {
      const response: AxiosResponse  = await api.get("/oauth2/authorize?redirect_url=http://localhost:3000/profile&scope=openid profile&client_id=articles-client&response_type=code");
      console.log(response.status);
      console.log(response.data);
    }

    initState();
  }, [])

  return <></>
}

export default Init;
```

After I should be redirected by Spring to the login page using the Spring Configuration:

```
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()).and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("http://localhost:3000/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/api/v1/login");
        return http.build();
    }
```

After React Login page using the `POST /api/v1/login` with my InMemoryUserDetailsManager I should enter credentials and get the code and in the end send a request to generate a token.

My Spring OAuth config is:

```
@Configuration
@Import(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.class)
public class OAuthSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource;

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        return http
                .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource).and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("http://localhost:3000/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/api/v1/login")
                .and()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("web")
                .clientSecret("secret")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .redirectUri("http://localhost:3000/authorized")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
                .scope("read")
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder()
                        .requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build())
                .tokenSettings(TokenSettings.builder()
                        .refreshTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofHours(10))
                        .build())
                .build();
        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);

    }

    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        RSAKey rsaKey = generateRsa();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return (jwkSelector, securityContext) -> jwkSelector.select(jwkSet);
    }

    private static RSAKey generateRsa() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        return new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
    }

    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
        return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    }
}
```

React App login component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import './App.css';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:9000",
});

function App() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState<string>("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>("");

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    const response: AxiosResponse = await api.post("/api/v1/login", {
      username,
      password
    });
    console.log(response.status);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h2>Welcome</h2>
      </header>
      <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
        <input id='username' name='username' placeholder='Username' value={username} onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}/>
        <input id='password' name='password' placeholder='Password' value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
        <button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But I am stuck on two issues:

1. CORS error during the init request `http://localhost:9000/oauth2/authorize?redirect_url=http://localhost:3000/profile&scope=openid%20profile&client_id=articles-client&response_type=code`
2. After the correct login redirect URL from Spring not contains code `http://localhost:9000/error?redirect_url=http://localhost:3000/profile&scope=openid%20profile&client_id=web&response_type=code&continue`

What did I do wrong with Spring OAuth?

Comment: Try enabling trace logging with `logging.level.org.springframework.security` as Spring Authorization Server will also log under that package. It might help you, otherwise post the logs here so we can take a look with you.

Comment: I'll also note that because you're using sessions, you really should not be disabling CSRF. You will need to learn how to integrate React with a CSRF protected backend. The [5.8 migration guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/exploits.html#_i_am_using_a_single_page_application_with_httpsessioncsrftokenrepository) has an example of a `/csrf` endpoint you can use to get started.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg thank you for the advice. I significantly appreciated your comments. 

But after doing some research during the days of thinking, we decided to go with Keycloak and Keycloakify to customize the login page. Keycloak has many features out of the box and is easy to configure with K8s. 

Thank you for your time!